# Что поставить: тире или дефис?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, существительные, приложение, дефис

Принципы определяют, каким образом спортсмены-участники Олимпийских игр могут заниматься коммерческой деятельностью

ИЛИ все же тире:

...спортсмены — участники Олимпийских игр

Приложение или нет? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае ставится **одно тире**:

*Принципы определяют, каким образом **спортсмены — участники Олимпийских игр** могут заниматься коммерческой деятельностью.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. Одно **тире** (первое или второе) опускается:

2. если приложение выражает **конкретное значение**, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее** или образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов Организации американских государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.); Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмены для участия в парусных гонках;

Comment: Это немного не то правило. У Розенталя нужного нет.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Где же вы пропадаете, oleedd, и правильное правило нам не ищете.  И чем же оно вам не показалось?  В чем принципиальна разница?

Comment: Они соединяют слово и фразу, я соединяю определяемое слово и распространенное приложение, у меня даже лучше получается, грамматические термины и все такое.

Comment: У Розенталя предложение продолжается от существительного после тире. А здесь у нас единое понятие, по факту здесь как дефис, но он очень нелепо бы выглядел перед фразой.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь необходимо **тире**. Если нужно соединить дефисом слово и фразу, то употребляется тире с пробелами, а не дефис.

Вопрос № 279916
Подскажите, пожалуйста, через дефис или тире? *Женщина - капитан дальнего плавания; компания - оператор электронных платежей.* Например, в контексте: *По заказу компании оператора электронных платежей эту работу выполнила Нина Евсеева - первая женщина-капитан дальнего плавания*.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

В сочетаниях с приложением, **если одна из частей содержит пробел**, вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак **тире**: *женщина-капитан*, но *женщина – капитан дальнего плавания*; *компания-оператор*, но *компания – оператор электронных платежей*.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.